# Sum of Fourier coefficients less than the norm of the respective vector

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

I have the following question to complete.

Let $X$ be an inner product space. Let $(e_{j})_{j\geq1}$ be an orthonormal sequence in $X$. Show that,
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|(x|e_{j})(y|e_{j})|\leq\|x\|\|y\|,
\end{align}
for all $x,y\in X$.

I have tried to use the Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality.

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|(x|e_{j})(y|e_{j})|\leq\|x\|\|y\|\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\|e_{j}\|^{2}.
\end{align}
However, that remaining sum, as far as I know, does not converge.

I tried to use Parseval's Identity, but that didn't work either. Can someone offer me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cauchy -Schwraz inequlairty for sequences rather than inner product. $|\sum \langle x,e_i \rangle \langle y,e_i \rangle| \leq (\sum |\langle x,e_i \rangle|^{2})^{1/2}(\sum |\langle y,e_i \rangle|^{2})^{1/2} \leq \|x\|\|y\|$.

Comment: I know this inequality as Bessel's Inequality. It works!

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality should just have $\|x\|\cdot\|y\|$ on the right hand side; you've got the statement of it mixed up.

In my post, the notation $(u|e_j)$ denotes the component of $u$ with respect to the unit vector $e_j$, which is equal to the inner product $\langle u,e_j\rangle$. This notation will never be used for anything other than a member of our orthonormal set $e_j$ in the second position.

Let $x_n$ be the projection onto the space spanned by the first $n$ of the $e_j$, and similarly for $y_n$. Then 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n (x|e_j)(y|e_j) = \langle x_n,y_n\rangle \le \|x_n\|\cdot \|y_n\| \le \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$$
There's no sum of $\|e_i\|^2$ there. And the equality is simply the inner product with respect to the standard (orthonormal) basis in $n$ dimensions.

Putting the absolute values in? Well, we could always rotate the $x|e_i$ and $y|e_i$ components to be positive; by orthogonality, that wouldn't affect $\|x_n\|$, $\|y_n\|$, or any of the other components.

To clarify about the absolute values:
Define $x'_n$ as follows: $x'_n=|(x|e_1)|e_1+|(x|e_2)|e_2+\cdots+|(x,e_n)|e_n$ - the sum of the absolute values of the components times the basis vectors - and similarly for $y'_n$. We claim that $\|x'_n\|=\|x_n\|$ and $\|y_n'\|=\|y_n\|$. Why? Because
$$\|x'_n\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^n |(x_n,e_j)|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n |(x,e_j)|^2=\|x_n\|^2$$
Then, applying this,
$$\sum_{j=1}^n |(x|e_j)|\cdot |(y|e_j)| = \langle x_n',y_n'\rangle \le \|x_n'\|\cdot \|y_n'\| = \|x_n\|\cdot \|y_n\| \le \|x\|\cdot \|y\|$$
by Cauchy-Schwarz for the first inequality and Parseval for the second. Done.

Comment: Doesn't Cauchy Schwartz state $|(x|y)|\leq\|x\|\|y\|$? If so, then for each element in the sum I can say $|(x|e_{j})||(y|e_{j})|\leq\|x\|\|e_{j}\|\|y\|\|e_{j}\|=\|x\|\|y\|\|e_{j}\|^{2}$. Is this not right?

Comment: The $e_j$ component of $x$ times the $e_j$ component of $y$ is one term of $\langle x,y\rangle$. Add all of them up (at least, if the $e_j$ are an orthonormal basis), and we get the inner product. At least, that's what I thought you were using that notation to mean. Using the full power of Cauchy-Schwarz to show that one component worth is less than the whole product of norms is incredibly wasteful.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. In fact I am now confused with my original question. I did state in the title that this was in regards to the Fourier coefficients of a vector, but I didn't realise that the inner products in the sum are being multiplied. 

I am aware that the Fourier coefficients for $x\in X$ are $(x|e_{j})$. Beyond that I am getting confused. Sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: Notation: I write inner products enclosed by the $\langle$ and $\rangle$ symbols. I interpreted your $|$ notation as components; since it was only applied with the orthonormal vectors $e_j$, these can also be read as inner products of $x$ and $y$ with that $e_j$ - but it's definitely a product of something for $x$ and something for $y$. Otherwise, why would there be two sets of parentheses?

Comment: Yes my $(\cdot|\cdot)$ notation implies an inner product.

Comment: Does this still mean your solution is correct? If so, could you please explain it a little more.

Comment: The only thing I am not understanding is, why is $(x|e_{j})$ the inner product of the component of $x$ with respect to $e_{j}$? Should it not be the inner product of $x$ with $e_{j}$. I do not understand how you have arrived at this.

Comment: It is the inner product of $x$ and $e_j$. It is also the $e_j$-component of $x$. That's kind of the point of a Fourier decomposition.